# How can I count XML nodes that start with a certain string using XQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following XML:

```
<prescriptions>
  <prescription id="1" amka="1">
    <status>closed</status>
    <doctor_info>
      <amka>111111</amka>
      <doc_code> 123</doc_code>
      <name> chris</name>
      <surname>st</surname>
      <specialization>path</specialization>
      <hospital>401</hospital>
    </doctor_info>
    <patient_info>
      <amka>1</amka>
      <genre>man</genre>
      <name>elton </name>
      <surname>kev</surname>
      <age>28</age>
      <adress>aaa123</adress>
      <home_phone>210</home_phone>
      <cell_phone>69</cell_phone>
      <email>aaa@aaa.com</email>
      <insurance>diom</insurance>
    </patient_info>
    <main_prescription>
      <type>eee</type>
      <epanalipseis>2</epanalipseis>
      <date>21/1/2012</date>
      <comms>blablabla</comms>
      <diagnosh>kkkk</diagnosh>
      <drug1>
        <onoma>prezza</onoma>
        <drastikh_ousia>llll</drastikh_ousia>
        <posotita>12</posotita>
        <dosologia>
          <arithmos_hapion>5</arithmos_hapion>
          <ores>2</ores>
          <hmeres>21</hmeres>
        </dosologia>
        <simetoxi>25%</simetoxi>
        <tropos_xorigisis>ass</tropos_xorigisis>
        <cost>100</cost>
      </drug1>
      <drug2>
        <onoma>prezza</onoma>
        <drastikh_ousia>llll</drastikh_ousia>
        <posotita>12</posotita>
        <dosologia>
          <arithmos_hapion>5</arithmos_hapion>
          <ores>2</ores>
          <hmeres>21</hmeres>
        </dosologia>
        <simetoxi>25%</simetoxi>
        <tropos_xorigisis>ass</tropos_xorigisis>
        <cost>100</cost>
      </drug2>
      <drug3>
        <onoma>prezza</onoma>
        <drastikh_ousia>llll</drastikh_ousia>
        <posotita>12</posotita>
        <dosologia>
          <arithmos_hapion>5</arithmos_hapion>
          <ores>2</ores>
          <hmeres>21</hmeres>
        </dosologia>
        <simetoxi>25%</simetoxi>
        <tropos_xorigisis>ass</tropos_xorigisis>
        <cost>100</cost>
      </drug3>
      <total_cost>100</total_cost>
      <prospou>nosokomeio</prospou>
      <drug_comms>ablablabla</drug_comms>
    </main_prescription>
  </prescription>
</prescriptions>
```

In `<main_prescription>` node I have 3 nodes for drugs: `<drug1> , <drug2>` and `<drug3>`.

Is there a way to count how many nodes name `<drug...>` are there using XQuery?

I am using the XQuery below but it is wrong:

```
select prescriptions.query('count(/prescriptions/prescription/main_prescription/drug[*])') as one1 from prescription
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

'count(/prescriptions/prescription/main_prescription/*[matches(name(), ''^drug[0-9]+$'')])

Here we are selecting all nodes which are having node names as 'drug' and ending with an integer.

You can explore more on xpath functions on the below link.
http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: Seems that SQL Server 2008 does not agree with the syntax giving the result:  Incorrect syntax near '0-9'.

Comment: you have to use escape character. I have modified the answer

Comment: @KaipaMSarma: I think that this expression doesn't select elements such as `drug99`. A correct Regex is: `^drug[0-9]+$`

Answer (score 2):

**The wanted nodes can be selected even with an XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
/*/*/main_prescription
      /*[starts-with(name(), 'drug')
       and
          substring-after(name(), 'drug')
         =
          floor(substring-after(name(), 'drug'))
        ]
```

**This selects all elements that**:

1. Are children of a `main_prescription` element that is a grand-child of the top element of the document and:
2. Have a name starting with the string `"drug"` and the remaining string after `"drug"` is an integer.

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of the functions `starts-with()`, `name()` and `substring-after()`.
2. Use of the fact that the expression `floor($x) = $x` evaluates to `true()` exactly when the string value of `$x` represents an integer.

Comment: Hi, Will floor function accepts string as argument. What happens if it encounters string as an argument.

Comment: @KaipaMSarma: In XPath 2.0, which is strongly typed, passing a non-numeric argument to `floor()` must result in error. In XPath 1.0, which is very weakly typed, `floor('3.5')` returns the number 3. `floor('Hi')` returns `NaN`. That is, the argument is converted to a number and then the function is applied.

Comment: ok.. got it now. I was wondering why it is throwing error for me.

Comment: @KaipaMSarma: in XPath 2.0 you must use explicit `xs:integer()` to convert the substring into an integer.